# Generalizing the central series to ordinal length

Tags: group-theory, ordinals

One can generalize the ascending and descending central series by transfinite induction, setting $G _{\alpha +1}=[G_\alpha, G]$ and $ G_\beta= \cap _{\alpha <\beta} G_\alpha $ (and analogously for the upper centers).

What is known about these series? Above all, if one of these series terminates, does the other series also terminate at the same ordinal ? Is there a characterization of the groups where it terminates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A free group $F$ is residually nilpotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Lower_central_series), that is, its lower central series has $$F_{\omega} = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} F_{n} =  \{ 1 \},$$ but if $F$ is non-abelian, then $F$ is centreless, so its upper central series never gets a chance.

Consider now the locally dihedral group $G = D(2^{\infty})$, which is the extension of [$Z(2^{\infty})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) by an involution inverting each element. Now $G$ is hypercentral (its upper central series terminates at $G$ after $\omega + 1$ steps), but the lower central series stops at $Z(2^{\infty})$. (See [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-02/S0002-9939-2010-10625-1/S0002-9939-2010-10625-1.pdf).)